# Publishing to User's Facebook Wall with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm integrating my web-based game to a Facebook Game . Facebook login, getting user id, getting user profile picture is OK . But i need to post somethings to wall (For example, *John Doe earned 50 point!*) .

I have **offline_access** and **publish_Stream** permissions for my Facebook App.

Now i want to publish some links automatically. I'm using [Facebook PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) with [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

I can get Facebook User ID etc... But i don't know how can i post somethings to user's wall, automatically (for example when user is offline).

I'm looking [Graph API Post document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)'s Publishing title. But i need access_token parameter for use this. And i'm not sure where is this access_token .

Comment: The access token will be picked up automatically by the SDK when the proper authentication cookie is set. You don't need to explicitly pass the access token as a parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing To User's Wall Without Being Online/Logged-in - Facebook Sharing Using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-using)

Comment: you only need the `publish_stream` permission and the user ID. Check the answer I linked to above and please use the search functionality for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **PHP-SDK 3.1.1**

To generate app and user tokens. **$app_access_token** & **$access_token**

*The user access_token if you have offline access will never expire, unless user deAuthorizes your app.  You would need to use for posting to a users wall when they are offline or not interacting with your application.*

---

```
<?php
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '135669679827333',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user) {
   try {
     // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
     $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     error_log($e);
     $user = null;
   }
 }
 if ($user) {
   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 } else {
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
 }
// Create Application Access Token
$app_access = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=135669679827333&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_access_token = file_get_contents($app_access);
// If we have a user who is logged in, create access_token with session.
if ($user) {
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [authentication doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) which will show you how to get an access token.

Comment: He doesn't need a user `access_token` if grant the `publish_stream` permission.

Answer (score 0):

you can get access token like this

```
               $access_token = $session['access_token'];
```

now use  $access_token where u need it

```
               $my_friends_ids=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$access_token);
```

here i am getting ids of all my friends